# Termux - Write access to usb pen drive

Tags: android, termux

I have termux on my android TV Box and I want to have write access to my plugged in usb pen. I have tried running `termux-setup-storage` command and it created $HOME/storage but this directory doesn't have a path to my usb drive. Maybe this command isn't thought to detect usb drives, only sdcards.
My usb drive is on /storage/udisk0 and I don't have write access in this directory. The group of /storage/udisk0 is *sdcard_r* . I can't seem to `chmod` `chown` or `chgrp` this directory.
Can someone help me?

Comment: just an idea: use `ln -s` to link the usb drive to your storage directory.

Comment: it doesn't work because then I don't have write access to the usb drive folder @MikhailKrutov

Comment: oh! I thought that some app misses the perms, not you yourself. Did you root your device?

Comment: I can `su` and enter the root user on termux. I also have SuperSu app installed (it came with the android box). Does this mean that my device is rooted @MikhailKrutov?

Comment: Yes, did you try to change perms from root account (or better, add yourself to group in question)?

Comment: @MikhailKrutov I have tried: adding myself to the directory group but termux doesn't have `adduser` command. I have also tried to change the directory group or chmod it to 777 via root user but it nothing is changed

Comment: I'm not really sure what commands are available to you, however http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/linux-add-user-to-group/ check this - there are multiple options of adding accounts to groups usually. Also, check mount options for the drive - it might be mounted read-only (which is likely the case due to 777 perms not working for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed the tutorial in http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/08/26/how-to-allow-apps-to-write-files-to-usb-mass-storage-devices-in-android/ and now I can write to my usb :)

Comment: uh... that "solution" appears to require a rootable device, which mine isn't.  Any other ideas?